# mathematical marxian models

Tags: mathematical-economics, marxism

Ive been doing some superficial reading on [Feldman-Mahalanobis Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldman%E2%80%93Mahalanobis_model) and have been wondering what other equations and "brand name" models that have been prodouced by marxist economists?

What other mathematical Marxian models are out there?

Answer (score 4):

Paul Samuelson wrote a series of papers formalizing Marxian economics, e.g. 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123567505500177

Comment: Is this Alex from Marginal University??????

Comment: Link leads to "page not found".